# How do I calculate end address of memory block allocated by malloc?

Tags: c, malloc

All we know malloc return the start address of allocated memory block but I would like  how do I count end address of this block

```
  int *p, *q;
  p=malloc(4*sizeof(int));
  q=p+4;
```

Now `q` will be pointing to end address block but I would like to have some other approach to get end address of memory block allocated by malloc.

**Edit**

One more thing I would like know here is there way to make sure that we are at end of allocated block

Comment: Actually you don't. The `4*sizeof(int)` will on almost any modern system result in 16. So +8 won't do the trick.

Comment: `p` points far after the end of the allocated memory. You need to add `4`, in most cases (even thought I think it's implementation defined). And why would you need other approaches about that?

Comment: @halfdan: you're sort of right, but seemingly for the wrong reason.  The +8 will advance the pointer by 8*sizeof(int) bytes.

Comment: Since you know you already allocated `4` `int`s worth of memory, you could do `p += 4`. But it's best to copy `p` so you can `free` it later.

Comment: @halfdan i am taking int as 2 byte long

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar - read more about pointer arithmetic. In short - `pointer + number` is `address_pointed_by_the_pointer + sizeof( the_pointed_type)`. So, it doesn't matter what's the size of an `int`. Adding `1` will move the pointer to the next element in the array.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: the 4 was correct; a `sizeof(int)` factor is implicit in the `p+4`.

Comment: @Amit - your platform ints are 2 bytes wide? `pointer + n` would result in moving the `pointer` by `n` steps dependent on what the pointer's underlying type is. If pointer were an `int *`, advancing or going backward by 1 would mean moving by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Calculating `p + 8` is [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior). During that calculation anything can happen: your computer may explode; your computer may transfer money to my bank account, ..., ...

Comment: I assumed the `8` was an honest mistake and changed it to a `4`. Apprently the `8` was the intended value ... and is an error!

Comment: @pmg Surely it's dereferencing `p+8` that is UB. Just calculating it is fine.

Comment: @David: no, calculating is UB. See 6.5.6/8 in the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: @pmg i got the point it should be 4 not 8 in this case

Comment: @pmg That would make it very inconvenient to test if a pointer was contained in a given block of memory.

Comment: @pmg I expect you are right and have edited my answer so that it (hopefully) does not come under attack from standards lawyers!  ;-)

Comment: @pmg OK, I read that. `p+4` is fine, but `p+5` is UB. So the standard specifically allows you to point to 1 past the end. That is very sensible.

Comment: @Amit Twice now I have converted i into I in your question. For future reference, please take a little more time and use the capital I.

Comment: @Amit No probs at all, just trying to help you out for the future!!

Comment: Please consider taking extended discussion to [chat] as it keeps questions/answers/comments leaner and cleaner, void of lengthy dialogue.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, using standard techniques, using just a pointer as input, determine where the end of the block lies. In order to do that. you would have to instrument your allocator or use an allocator that provided such functionality.

When you allocate memory with `malloc` the responsibility is entirely down to you the programmer to keep track of how much memory you allocated. You cannot ask the system, at some later point in time, to tell you any information about the memory block.

Comment: @davis is there any way to make sure that we have reached at end of memory block?

Comment: What do you mean by that question?

Comment: Suppose some has made an error(p=p+8 in this case) like I made while doing pointer arithmetic ,then is there any way to recover from that .

Comment: @Amit No, there is no provision for range checking or fault tolerance in C. You have to write code with no defects in. It's tough.

Comment: This is for what we have valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote (p=p+8) will have p pointing to beyond the end, since you allocated space for 4 ints but shifted the pointer by 8 (ints, not bytes).

One way to do it is trivial:

```
size_t const SIZE = 4;
int *p;
p=malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
p=p+SIZE;
```

Now, no bug, and no likely future one either.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know how much space you asked for, you are out of luck, since this is not part of the contract of `malloc(3)`'. Some particular implementations of malloc support an API for this, but it is not portably.

So, you cannot unless you write your own `malloc`.

If you really want to know the total amount of memory allocated, you are even further out of luck. If `malloc` returns value `p` for size `q`, then the storage can start at any `p-X` and extend to `p-X+q+Y`, for any values of X and Y that the implementors of `malloc` found convenient for their own overhead.

The right way to detect errors in pointer usage is to use a tool like valgrind.

Comment: Where do X and Y come into it? If `malloc(q)` returns `p` then the memory starts at `p` and extends to `p+q-1` (my pointers are `char*`) in this comment.

Comment: When malloc returns `p` it has usually allocated some bytes of overhead before p and maybe some guard afterwards.

Comment: Of course there may be block headers but that's all private. Accessing it is UB.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I originally understood this question to be about private overhead, not 'gee I forgot to write down what I malloced'.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to work out exactly what was being asked too.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly late answer, but I figure this needs a mention:
For Visual Studio, you can use [_msize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to calculate the number supplied to `malloc()` (or number of bytes allocated by `new x`, if you're using C++). It only works for pointers allocated on the heap though, so `_malloca()`, `alloca()`, `char x[2];` won't work.